# double superscript in keynote

Tags: keynote, text

Is there a way to do a double superscript/subscript in keynote?

I mean superscript of a superscript, e.g., (in latex notation) $a^{2^n}$.

Comment: Have you tried raising the baseline after making it superscript? http://support.apple.com/kb/PH6034

Comment: I think for such an expression it's best to use an equation editor, like MathType or a Latex generator, and then insert the resulting image/object into your keynote doc.  Keynote has an Insert > Mathtype menu item.